# How do I force a discriminated union to stay discriminated

Tags: typescript

I have a object literal type which I am using to dynamically generate forms and I want type-checking to work correctly throughout several different arrays.

```
export type Intersect<T> = (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends (
  x: infer R
) => any
  ? R
  : never;
type IndexableKeyTypes = string | number | symbol
type Indexable<T = unknown> = Record<string | number, T>
type JustIndexableTypes<T> = T extends IndexableKeyTypes ? T : never
type IndexableKeys<Rec> = KeysMatching<Rec, IndexableKeyTypes>;

type KeysMatching<Rec, Keys> = NonNullable<
  {
    [RecKey in keyof Rec]: Rec[RecKey] extends Keys ? RecKey : never
  }[keyof Rec]
>

export type GroupBy<T extends Indexable, K extends IndexableKeys<T>> = {
  [KV in JustIndexableTypes<T[K]>]: T extends Record<K, KV> ? T : never
}
export type ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<T, TKey extends keyof Intersect<T> = keyof Intersect<T>> =
  T extends Record<TKey, any> ? {
    [P in TKey]: T extends Record<P, any> ? (k: T[P]) => void : never;
  }[TKey] extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never : never;
/* T extends string | number | symbol | Function | undefined | null | Array<any> ? T : */
type KeysAny<T> = T extends any ? { [P in keyof T]: any } : never;
type AllPossibleTypes<T> = NextAllPossibleTypes<{ [K in keyof Intersect<KeysAny<T>>]: ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<T, K>; }>;
//T[K] extends string | number | symbol | Function | undefined | null | Array<any> ? T[K] :
type NextAllPossibleTypes<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends string | number | symbol | Function | undefined | null | Array<any> ? T[K] : AllPossibleTypes<T[K]> }
type Raise<L extends keyof T[keyof T], T extends Record<string, Record<L, any>>> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K][L] };
type PickField<T, K extends string> = T extends Record<K, any> ? T[K] : never;
type GetFieldAttributesFor<M extends keyof (typeof zschema.models), F extends keyof (typeof zschema.models)[M]["fields"]> = PickField<(typeof zschema.models)[M]["fields"][F], "attributes">;
type GetTableAttributesFor<M extends keyof (typeof zschema.models)> = PickField<(typeof zschema.models)[M], "attributes">;

/** This one works properly */
export type FieldAttributes = {
    [M in keyof (typeof zschema.models)]: {
        [F in keyof (typeof zschema.models)[M]["fields"]]: {
            [I in keyof GetFieldAttributesFor<M, F> & number]: GetFieldAttributesFor<M, F>[I];
        }[keyof GetFieldAttributesFor<M, F> & number]
    }[keyof (typeof zschema.models)[M]["fields"]]
}[keyof (typeof zschema.models)];

/** This doesn't, discriminated types are collapsed */
export type TableAttributes2 = {
    [M in keyof (typeof zschema.models)]: {
        [I in keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]: {
            key: GetTableAttributesFor<M>[I]["type"];
            val: GetTableAttributesFor<M>[I]["properties"];
        };
    }[keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]
}[keyof (typeof zschema.models)];

/** The solution, for no discernable reason */
export type TableAttributes1 = {
    [M in keyof (typeof zschema.models)]: {
        [I in keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]: GetTableAttributesFor<M>[I]
    }[keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]
}[keyof (typeof zschema.models)];

/** Final working copy for demo purposes */
export type TableAttributes = NextAllPossibleTypes<Raise<"properties",GroupBy<{
    [M in keyof (typeof zschema.models)]: {
        [I in keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]: GetTableAttributesFor<M>[I]
    }[keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]
}[keyof (typeof zschema.models)], "type">>>;

declare const zschema: {
  models: {
    "Billing": {
      "name": "Billing",
      "fields": {
        "id": {
          "name": "id",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "ID",
          "isRequired": true,
          "attributes": []
        },
        "rentalID": {
          "name": "rentalID",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "ID",
          "isRequired": true,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "type": "index",
              "properties": {
                "name": "byRental"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "Amount": {
          "name": "Amount",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "Float",
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": []
        },
        "Date": {
          "name": "Date",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "AWSDate",
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": []
        },
        "Recurrance": {
          "name": "Recurrance",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "Boolean",
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": []
        },
        "LineItems": {
          "name": "LineItems",
          "isArray": true,
          "type": {
            "nonModel": "LineItem"
          },
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": [],
          "isArrayNullable": false
        },
        "customerID": {
          "name": "customerID",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "ID",
          "isRequired": true,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "type": "index",
              "properties": {
                "name": "byCustomer"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "PaymentRecord": {
          "name": "PaymentRecord",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "String",
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": []
        },
        "Status": {
          "name": "Status",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": {
            "enum": "BillingStatus"
          },
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": []
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "name": "createdAt",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "AWSDateTime",
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": [],
          "isReadOnly": true
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "name": "updatedAt",
          "isArray": false,
          "type": "AWSDateTime",
          "isRequired": false,
          "attributes": [],
          "isReadOnly": true
        }
      },
      "syncable": true,
      "pluralName": "Billings",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "type": "model",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "key",
          "properties": {
            "name": "byRental",
            "fields": [
              "rentalID"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "key",
          "properties": {
            "name": "byCustomer",
            "fields": [
              "customerID"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "auth",
          "properties": {
            "rules": [
              {
                "allow": "public",
                "operations": [
                  "create",
                  "update",
                  "delete",
                  "read"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

The schema data is at the bottom of this code block. You can copy the entire thing into typescript playground. Yes, I know it's not secure. It's an early stage project.

The code oddly results in both keys being automatically combined into one object, ruining the entire point of discriminated unions. As I've now found a solution, which I included, I'm curious what changed and why.

```
type TableAttributes2 = {
    key: "model" | "auth";
    val: {} | {
        rules: [{
            allow: "public";
            operations: ["create", "update", "delete", "read"];
        }];
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow, uh, could you give us a [mre]?  This is not reproducible (depends on undeclared types and undefined values) and I'm really hoping it's not minimal because it's huge.

Comment: @jcalz done. You can paste the code into typescript playground.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what difference this makes, but this one works properly. I changed the value of `[I in keyof ...]` as shown and now it works.

```
/** The solution, for no discernable reason */
export type TableAttributes1 = {
    [M in keyof (typeof zschema.models)]: {
        [I in keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]: GetTableAttributesFor<M>[I]
    }[keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]
}[keyof (typeof zschema.models)];

/** Final working type */
export type TableAttributes = NextAllPossibleTypes<Raise<"properties",GroupBy<{
    [M in keyof (typeof zschema.models)]: {
        [I in keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]: GetTableAttributesFor<M>[I]
    }[keyof GetTableAttributesFor<M> & number]
}[keyof (typeof zschema.models)], "type">>>;
```